# Designer support for DataAdapters in .net6 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net-6.0, designer, sqldataadapter, dataadapter

We are moving our applications from .net Framework48 to .net6.
We are using the Visual Studio Designer for DataAdapters in Visual Studio 2022 but after we moved to .net6 the support for designing DataAdapters seems to be gone. Is this correct?
Are there any other soulutions to get the Desigener to work in .net6 for DataAdapters?

Visual Studio is reporting:
[11:46:08.162331] fail: [AuthorizationAdm]: Failed to load assembly: Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyName, ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Types.AssemblySearchingTypeIdentityResolutionService.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)

```
                    For information on how to troubleshoot the designer refer to the guide at https://aka.ms/winforms/designer/troubleshooting.
```

Get support for designing dataAdapters in .net6